# how to decode an encoded image string using base64

Tags: php

I am trying this code but not getting img as output. please help me or suggest any other way.how to display the image.

```
<?php 
function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {


    $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

print_r($data[1]);
    return $output_file; 
}

 $my_base64_string = "data:image/png;base64,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";
  $image = base64_to_jpeg( $my_base64_string, 'tmp.jpg' );                 
?>

<img src="tmp.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

 $my_base64_string = "data:image/png;base64,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";

  $data = explode(',', $my_base64_string );
  $image = base64_decode($data[1]);        
  $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png'; 
  $success = file_put_contents($file, $image);
  print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';        
?>
```

OutPut
[image]

Comment: I have got it. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Use base64 string as src in your html.

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64..." />
```